# The correct way of accessing user data within page rendering in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I have an app where like most apps users register and their data is saved in a user document in MongoDB using Mongoose.

Now the important point to know is that I am using Node.js & rendering my pages within each route, using the EJS Tempting engine.

**An Example of rendering pages:**

```
 app.get('/profile',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
```

Now you can see in the above code that Im checking whether the user is loggedIn & then passing the user object to my template. The user object contains the whole user document for the signed in user.

**How I use the User Object:**

On the front end when the user access their profile, I use the `user: req.user` object to access the signed users document `ID` and use that I'd to get information related to that user.

For example:

1. Get all comments matching the logged in users ID
2. Get all posts matching the logged in users ID

**Heres an example of it:**

```
<body ng-init="getUserPosts('<%= user._id %>')"></body>
```

The above works perfectly, I use the same technique many times, overtime I need the users ID to get data related to that user or post to that user account, for example:

```
<button ng-click="savePost('<%= user._id %>')">Send</button>
```

The above finds the user with the given ID (which is always the loggedIn user) saves the posts to their account.

**The Issue:**

Now my code works perfectly I have had no issues but I noticed that when I inspect element my page in any browser I can clearly see the Users ID. Below is an image to help understand what I mean:

[image]

**Now I understand that only the loggedIn user will able to view only their own ID. But still is this the correct way? Is this harmful? How can I improve on this?**

Comment: One method I've come across is filtering out the `_id` of the user ofbject and sending down an encrypted value. When the server recieves the encrypted `_id`, it just decrypts it then proceeds as normal. This means the true `_id` is never exposed to the user, who could do damage with it elsewhere.

Comment: You'd better have some kind of server-side security check if you're going to do something like `<button ng-click="savePost('<%= user._id %>')">Send</button>` - otherwise there's nothing to stop someone just modifying the code and saving posts as whoever they want.

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks for the comment. Currently the only check I do is checking whether the user is authenticated loggedIn user. What else would you suggest ? or is their a completely different way of doing this?

Comment: @AlexLogan thanks for the comment. Would you be able to provide with an example of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, one approach would be to encrypt the `user._id` value and then send it to the client.

```
app.get('/profile',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
    var user = req.user;
    user._id = encrypt(user._id);
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user: user
    });
});
```

This means in the html you get

```
<button ng-click="savePost('someEncryptedValue')">Send</button>
```

Your raw mongo id is no longer being exposed to the client.

On the back end you would first decrypt the value, then proceed as you would.

```
app.get(/userPosts,function(req,res){
    var userId = decrypt(req.query.id);
    Posts.find({userId:userId},function(err,posts){
        res.send(posts);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you tend to use/recommend using to actually perform the encryption?

Comment: Thanks guys you both have been a great help. I just wanna make sure I do stuff the right way. Again thanks!

Comment: There's no right way to do it. For a pet project, using id's is fine however if you're going to be exposed to millions of users, exposing a persons id may not be so sensible, as they could use it to attack your system or modify their own account. Also mongo ids are easily recognizable, telling a hacker exactly what kind of database you're using giving them an advantage if an attack is attempted.

Comment: @AlexLogan Thanks for the info mate. Although my App won't be used by millions of users, it will still be used by clients. So I will be using your suggestion of encrypting data.